# GAMs falsely suggest non-linear function (edf>2) for about 15-25% of simulated data?

Tags: simulation, nonlinear-regression, mgcv, gamm4

I've been learning about GAMs and was curious about how sensitive they are to noise within a given sample. I know people generally say that GAMs are more prone to overfitting than GLMs and need to be validated or cross-validated, but little more is said about *how* prone they are to overfitting. I ran a simple simulation in which two variables are linearly correlated (with added gaussian noise) and then used the gam function from the R package 'mgcv' to see if the gam could recover the linear association or if it started fitting to noise and suggesting non-linear associations. Using the default gam settings, I repeated this process ~500x and found that the gam suggested an edf>2 (i.e. a non-linear association) around 25% of the time! When I switched to REML the false EDF rate fell to around 15% which is better, but still concerning. Is this a problem that most within the GAM community are aware of? It seems like a significant problem to me because this overfitting rate is fairly high (~15-25%) and I can imagine may become even higher as more non-linear parameters enter the model. Having said that, I'm still very new to these models and would love to hear from people in the community that are well acquainted with GAMs.

Here is the full R code I used for my simulation:

```
#let's create two continuous variables
library(MASS)
library(mgcv)
library(tidymv)

plots = 0 # set to 1 if you want a scatterplot and smooth for each iteration (will slow down run time a lot!)
iterations = 500 # number of times to rerun the analysis
n = 75 #number of data points to simulate
correlation = .3 # correlation between simulated variables
method = 'GCV.Cp' #REML or GCV.Cp

set.seed(1) # for reproducibility
edf_all = NULL # the edf for each iteration will be stored here
aic_comp_all = NULL #the aic comparison between linear and nonlinear models will be stored here
bic_comp_all = NULL #same as above but for BIC
pval_smooth_all = NULL # significance of smooth term stored here
pval_reg_all = NULL # significance of linear term stored here
pval_lm_all = NULL
for (j in seq(iterations)) {
  # this is the correlation matrix for the simulated data
  Sigma       <- matrix(c(1,correlation,correlation,1),2,2) 
  # this simulates the data
  sim_data    <-as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n= n, mu = c(0,0), Sigma = Sigma)) 
  #now run gam with a single smooth term
  gam_results <- gam(V1 ~ s(V2),
                          data = sim_data,
                          method = method)
  reg_results <- gam(V1 ~ V2,
                     data = sim_data,
                     method = method)
  
  sum_reg     <- summary(reg_results)
  sum_res     <- summary(gam_results)
  
  #store edf, aic/bic comparisons and pvalues
  edf_all[j]         <- sum_res$edf
  
  aics               <- AIC(reg_results,gam_results)
  aic_comp           <- aics$AIC[1]>aics$AIC[2]
  aic_comp_all[j]    <- aic_comp
  
  bics               <- BIC(reg_results,gam_results)
  bic_comp           <- bics$BIC[1]>bics$BIC[2]
  bic_comp_all[j]    <- bic_comp
  
  pval_smooth_all[j] <- sum_res$s.pv
  pval_reg_all[j]    <- sum_reg$p.pv[2]
  
  #plot stuff if you want 
  if (plots == 1) {
    plot(sim_data)
    smooths<-plot_smooths(model = gam_results, series = V2)
    print(smooths)
  }
  print(paste0('done with iteration ', j))
}

hist(edf_all, iterations)
sum(edf_all>2)/ iterations #this is the percent of times the edf is estimated to be > 2
sum(aic_comp_all)/ iterations # this is the percent of times the AIC is said to be lower for non-linear relative to linear
sum(bic_comp_all)/ iterations # same but for BIC
sum(pval_smooth_all<.05) /iterations # percent of significant p-values for non-linear
sum(pval_reg_all<.05) /iterations # percent of significant p-values for linear
```

Comment: Tests are *usually* pretty good about having $U(0, 1)$-distributed p-values when the null hypothesis is true like it is supposed to be in your simulation. I wonder if you’re conditioning on something that isn’t part of the test assumptions.

Comment: how does this change if the sample size is significantly increased? Say from 75 to 750? One possibility is that the asymptotics of the test statistic haven't kicked in yet.

Comment: @JohnMadden Nice catch! I remember seeing this in a likelihood ratio test on a sample of three or four where that was too small for the $\chi^2$ approximation to be close to accurate.

Comment: @Dave Sorry I'm not sure I understand... the correlation is .3 between variables in the simulation above. When I set it to zero the number of pvals below .05 are right around 5% as one would expect. The histogram suggests they are nicely uniformly distributed.

Comment: @VictorPokorny Then how are you rejecting more than $5\%$ of the time?

Comment: @JohnMadden Changing sample size has surprisingly little effect on the false EDF rate. When I set it to 750, the gam suggests the edf is > 2 for about 20% of the samples.

Comment: @Dave I think the confusion is that I'm talking about a "false EDF rate" which is different from the false positive rate. The false EDF rate is just a clumsy term I made up to describe the fact that the GAM is falsely suggesting a non-linear association (edf>2) for about 20% of samples.

Comment: What is the `edf` and what is special about two?

Comment: First, we expect that you should recover a significant slope for V2. The smooth terms in the gam contain the linear function, so I'm not sure why the p-values of the terms of much interest, since the GAM should also return that the V2 term is significant. Second, while $edf\approx 1$ is close to a linear term, it is not clear what frequency properties we ought to expect out of the edf itself. Third, it isn't clear to me what you mean by overfitting. As you will have noticed, after fitting, the fitted smooths are pretty much straight lines.

Comment: @user1848065 Yah the p-values were mainly so I could test if the non-linear gam had a higher type-1 error rate then a typical linear model. This only makes sense when the correlation is set to zero so that the null hypothesis is true. FWIW I did find that the type-1 error rate was a bit higher for the non-linear model when using the default settings. The point I'm trying to get at with the EDF is that we know for a fact that the EDF should be 1 (because I created the data) and yet 15-25% of the time the GAM gets it wrong and says it non-linear.

Comment: @Dave EDF is the estimated degrees of freedom for the non-linear smooth function that GAMs use to describe the relationship between IV and DV. An EDF of 1 is a linear function; as the EDF gets higher the function becomes more "wiggly". Setting the threshold at two is a bit arbitrary. In publications, authors have said that an EDF > 2 suggests a "highly non-linear" function: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/The-effective-degrees-of-freedom-edf-estimated-from-generalized-additive-models-were_fig3_302976371

Comment: @Dave If I wanted to be a real stickler I would set the EDF threshold such that any EDF greater than one is false non-linearity, but that seems overly strict because an EDF of 1.1 or 1.3 is still a fairly linear function with just a bit of curve to it. When EDFs are greater than 2 the functions start to become noticeably non-linear.

Comment: @VictorPokorny I see what you are getting at, but the problem with using the EDF to say that there is something problematic with the model is that as far as I know, we don't know how to use the EDF as a test statistic. You want to use the EDF to declare that a non-linear trend has been found, but we don't know what the appropriate cutoff ought to be to guarantee with high probability that the identified trend is non-linear. The sampling distribution of the EDF is not known to me at least.

Comment: @user1848065 thanks for the feedback! I don't know if I agree that we need to know the sampling distribution of the EDF in order to know whether the model is fitting a linear or non-linear function. I can plot the smooths and see for myself that when EDF is > 2 that the smooth is distinctly non-linear. Here is a link to a screenshot of a smooth with EDF of 1.78 (which is less than the cut-off I'm using). You can see the function is non-linear: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eB0NbwMB9-enw4VYSMptOhp-tqaBzoOn/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: @user1848065 I think I see what you're saying though. It would be nice to have an EDF sampling distribution to be able to say, the estimated function is "significantly" non-linear (i.e. the EDF is significantly different from 1). I think, in practice, researchers using GAMs look at the EDF and the shape of the function and decide whether they think the estimated function is sufficiently non-linear to justify using a non-linear model. If the function looks "linear-ish" they would likely opt for a linear model. Publications tend to suggest EDFs>2 are suggestive of "highly non-linear" functions

Comment: @VictorPokorny Yeah, I agree, the EDF is a fine heuristic to use to guide the modeling and understanding of the data, but I wouldn't use it to claim significance. Just an indication, in addition to whatever domain knowledge you might have.

Comment: To what p-values do EDFs around two correspond? It might be that such a value just corresponds to a liberal $\alpha$-level more like $0.1$ or $0.2$, rather than a more traditional (for better or for worse) value of $0.05$, so if you expect such an EDF value in $5\%$ of cases where there is no nonlinearity, you are going to be in for a surprise. (After all, you said the p-values are about $U(0, 1)$ when the null hypothesis is true.)

Comment: @Dave I don't know of any work that directly relates EDF values to p-values (but I'm also a GAM neophyte!). I am primarily concerned about the fact that a well-intentioned researcher could input their data into a gam and the gam could suggest a "highly non-linear function" (edf>2) and choose to model their data that way, when in actuality the relation is linear and the GAM is just overfitting to noise. It's concerning to me that using the default settings, this can happen about 25% of the time.